# Why is obvious spam put on hold?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, spam

[This user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88581/user88581?tab=questions&sort=activity) (among others) has been posting a lot of questions lately which contain nothing but spam. I'm not sure about the reason for the posts, but I would guess it has to do with search engine indexing. In that case, the longer the posts are active on math.SE, the more the user will profit from spamming.

I'm quite new here, so I might have misunderstood this, but I'm under the impression that the rules for deletion were changed quite recently, and nowadays posts that should be deleted are put on hold for a limited time before getting deleted.

If not available, I suggest that the moderators are equipped with the possibility to immediately remove obvious spam posts, such as the ones linked above. Apart from improving the signal-to-noise ratio in the question lists, it would also discourage spammers from using this site for their purposes (whatever they might be).

EDIT: Well, the linked user was banned while I was writing this. Users can obviously be banned, which causes all his/her questions to be deleted immediately. But what about individual questions? Isn't the [on hold] process unnecessary when it comes to very obvious spam posts?

Comment: Since the user and the posts are gone, could you describe the spammy nature of the content? I guess I've been lucky (or blind) not to have clicked-through to any "obvious spam", so I'm curious about what I've missed.

Comment: The content is about anything from artificial grass to apartments in Shanghai. I don't have anything saved, but it's very obvious spam. However, no malicious links (no links at all for that matter) are posted, and it has nothing to do with scamming. That's why I think the reason is to increase the hit rate on google for certain search terms (or something related).

Comment: At least two of the posts were from other Q and A sites. One "question" was lifted from here http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130806200253AAT6ZE5 another from and another from http://able2know.org/topic/219970-1 Other stack exchange sites are also getting these questions.

Comment: Are there any links to the now-deleted spam? I'm intrigued.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Try [user88581 site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=user88581+site:math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Moderators are not everywhere. We are only aware of flags if you raise them.

(I've deleted the posts before you even finished composed your Meta posting here... your "this user" link is already dead.)

What you can do to help:

### Flags Ahoy!!!

For obvious spam posts, instead of voting to close, or flagging as off-topic, you should just flag it as Spam.

Spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam.

If enough people agree with you then the question will be automatically deleted by the community user.

---

As an aside, the voting to close mechanism has never implied deletion! Some closed questions are cleaned up automatically (those with negative scores and no answers, or duplicates, or migrated ones). But not all closed questions are deleted. Deletion requires either an accumulation of spam or offensive flags, moderator action, or deletion votes cast by suitable number of 10/20K users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Willie! This questions is obviously a result of a misunderstanding on my part. I thought the [on hold] thing was caused by moderators, but it's the vote to close feature by "normal" users that causes this. I think I got it!

Comment: @DanielR: this site (and other SE sites) is very big on community moderation. Whenever possible decisions are crowd sourced to the entire community. Obviously there are certain things (like spammers) that can be treated with expediency and it is for that purpose (and some other small maintenance type things) that Moderators exist. So don't hesitate to use the flag if you see something you think ought to be fixed by the moderators.